# Release Xcode 6 Beta, iOS 7 app to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I've been working on an app for a client and decided to build it in Swift since I knew their release date would be very late in the year, possibly around late November. However, they've now decided to cut features for an earlier release date and I'm a little bit stuck. Can we still release an iOS 7 app built in Swift and Xcode 6 Beta to the App Store? If not, is there some way of building it in Xcode 5 without have to re-write all the swift files, of which there are many?

Comment: Nope, you'll have to chalk this up to a life lesson.  First of all, don't start developing with things while they are still in beta, and second of all don't ever trust your clients.

Comment: @borrrden in which case when can we expect Xcode 6 to be available for full release? As that is the only way I see this getting released the app without redoing it in Objective-C which would be a shame.

Comment: I imagine it will be around September to coincide with the release of the new iPhone but that's only speculation based on past behavior.

Comment: There is normally a small period before the release of the new iOS that Apple will start allowing developers to submit apps for the new iOS I think normally this is 2 weeks before but don't hold me to that.

Comment: Hmm, thanks guys. Not sure if I'll be able to risk it without a firm release date even though you guys are indicating that it could be around mid-September which would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Swift is only available in Xcode 6 so unfortunately, you will not be able to release it to the app store till Xcode 6 is released.

Comment: @borrrden I was under this impression that apps developed using swift could only be submitted using xcode 6. However this was only from word of mouth on here I haven't really looked into myself as I have been told by my company that we will continue with objective-c for now. So I haven't read it from official apple docs but I have read on here in a few posts. Maybe you could share the docs for this so I could have a read myself.

Comment: @Popeye I might have misunderstood what OP is saying.  I read it as "You cannot use Objective-C, only Swift on Xcode 6".  However, it might be saying "You can only use Swift on Xcode 6, not Xcode 5."  Sorry if I read it wrong.

Comment: @borrrden I'am also curious, Can we develop app using swift other than in Xcode 6 now?

Comment: @borrrden I tried developing a swift application first on Xcode 5. It did not support it. I then switched over to Xcode 6 Beta and I was able to write swift apps. It is provided in the documentation that Swift is introduced in Xcode 6 : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/WhatsNewXcode.pdf

Comment: @shaveenk My apologies, I misunderstood your sentence as I mentioned above.  Could you correct it to use more unambiguous English?  After that I will remove my downvote.  Example sentence:  "As far as I know, you can only develop Swift *by using* Xcode 6"  Actually it's my fault for not considering the context of the sentence, but I cannot undo my downvote unless there is an edit.

Comment: Hi guys, to clear up any ambiguity, my question is purely about releasing to the app store from Xcode 6. However, your answer is relevant in that if I can't develop swift outside of the beta then the only option is to release the app through Xcode 6.

Comment: @borrrden I've not seen many users apologize when they are wrong they normally defend their answers to the death, so hats off to you sir for being the bigger man.

Comment: @shaveenk I edited the wording so I could remove my downvote, but regardless Marcin is right in that only half of the question is answered.  You should consider adding that you cannot release to the app store with Xcode 6 until it is out of beta so the OP is out of luck.

Comment: @Popeye I defend my answers to the death as well...when they're right ^^